# Klein bottle homeomorphic to union of Möbius strip

Tags: general-topology, klein-bottle, mobius-band

I'm having trouble showing that the Klein bottle defined as a quotient space of $I^2$ with relation $(x,-1)R(x,1)$ and $(-1,y)R(1,-y)$  is Hausdorff and that it can be expressed as $X\cup Y$ where $X,Y$ are homeomorphic to the Möbius strip and $X\cap Y$ is homeomorphic to $S^1$.

Comment: Your description of $R$ seems to be missing a minus sign on one of the $x$'s or on one of the $y$'s.  As it stands, the quotient is not a Klein bottle but a torus.

Comment: ah thank you I forgot to include a minus sign on y

Comment: Maybe the picture [found here](http://plus.maths.org/content/imaging-maths-inside-klein-bottle) will help you visualize it.

Answer (score 3):

This crude drawing may be helpful.
[image]